# Angular SSR: Get Request instance (for grabbing headers) inside a route resolver

Tags: angular, transloco, angular-ssr

I'm working on an SSR project and trying to get the users request headers sent to the node server to parse the accepted language header param inside an angular resolver.

What Im trying to do is redirect the users root route to a preferred language setting, either accepted-lang headers or the default lang.

When Im trying to inject the Request instance, its always null/undefined

The DefaultLang Resolver:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DefaultlanguageResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {
  translocoService = inject(TranslocoService);
  navigationService = inject(NavigationService);
  request = inject(Request, { optional: true });
  appConfig = inject(APP_CONFIG);

  resolve(
    _route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    _state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {

    // this.request is always null/undefined

    const headerLang = this.request?.headers
      ? this.request.headers.get('accept-language')
      : null;

    if (
      headerLang &&
      this.appConfig.availableLangs.find((lang) => lang === headerLang)
    ) {
      this.translocoService.setActiveLang(headerLang);
    } else {
      this.translocoService.setActiveLang(
        this.translocoService.getDefaultLang()
      );
    }

    this.navigationService.navigateToRoot();
    return true;
  }
}
```

My routes:

```js
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    resolve: [DefaultlanguageResolver],
    // Required component property
    component: LayoutComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':lang',
    resolve: [LanguageResolver],
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [...]
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you hosting your angular app through `start:ssr` directly, or through a backend like ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR;

```js
import {isPlatformServer} from "@angular/common";
import {Request} from "express";
import {REQUEST} from "@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens";

// ...

constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: any,
    @Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) request: Request | null) {
    if (isPlatformServer(platformId)) {
        request?.header('Accept-Language');
        // request.acceptsLanguages() // Good utility for language preferences
    }
}
```

## SEASON 01

Angular being design to be platform agnostic (okay, to some extent), you either render Angular pages using:

- The browser: `@angular/platform-browser`

  > Supports execution of Angular apps on different supported browsers.
  >
  > — https://angular.io/api/platform-browser
- The Server: `@angular/platform-server`

  > Supports delivery of Angular apps on a server, for use with server-side rendering (SSR).
  >
  > — https://angular.io/api/platform-server

A quick thinkering of these wordings and the Angular architecture reveals that Angular still need environment specifics to come around rendering, and deals with differences between browsers but also servers. Hence the need for:

- `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`

  > Supports JIT compilation and execution of Angular apps on different supported browsers.
  >
  > — https://angular.io/api/platform-browser-dynamic
- `@nguniversal/express-engine`

  > This is an Express Engine for running Angular Apps on the server for server side rendering.
  >
  > — https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/e1c5336536b985461d49dd5cea457aecac4be1bc/modules/express-engine/README.md#angular-express-engine

[See for yourself in the source code](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/e1c5336536b985461d49dd5cea457aecac4be1bc/modules/express-engine/src/main.ts#L76) how on the server, `@nguniversal/express-engine` provides us with token/value for `REQUEST` and `RESPONSE`...

```js
function getReqResProviders(req: Request, res?: Response): StaticProvider[] {
  const providers: StaticProvider[] = [
    {
      provide: REQUEST,
      useValue: req,
    },
  ];
  if (res) {
    providers.push({
      provide: RESPONSE,
      useValue: res,
    });
  }

  return providers;
}
```

[...during options configuration of the Express view engine.](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/e1c5336536b985461d49dd5cea457aecac4be1bc/modules/express-engine/src/main.ts#L53)

```js
renderOptions.providers = [...(renderOptions.providers ?? []), getReqResProviders(req, res)];
```

> **NOTE:** And, because you're likely rendering your app in other environments, consider the `Optional()` injection modifier, and the type signature, and the condition, to gracefully handle everything.

Here is the documentation [about the `Optional` modifier](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional), for further readings on it.

Comment: Ok. But this will only work if the angular app is hosted directly through `start:ssr` and not through eg. ASP.NET Core

Comment: Well, (1) the OP wasn't ASP-oriented, (2) I run `dev:ssr` on local and NodeJS/Docker in production, (3) I am not a reference when it comes to ASP, (4) ASP support for for Angular SSR seems deprecated - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine , (5) ASP/SSR intergation seems to be a wrap up that invokes NodeJS under the hood as mentioned here - https://trilon.io/blog/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-deep-dive#aspnet-core-angular-universal-integration - and demonstrated in the `Dockerfile` of the repository a few lines below that last reference.